# The app crashes with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I am facing the ClassNotFoundException while launching my application.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
>   com.tsf.esharp.DataSystem: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.tsf.esharp.DataSystem     at
>   android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:482)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3952)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:128)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
>     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tsf.esharp.DataSystem
>     at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
>     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:946)
>     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:477)
>     ... 11 more
>   Force finishing activity com.tsf.esharp.ui.activity/.LauncherActivity

I am facing this problem once after I introduced a library project and added it to my application. Can anybody know what could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a ClassNotFoundException for a number of reasons. Usually it is when a library is not imported properly or there is confusion over which class to use, e.g. if you have two packages with similar names and the same class in each of them.

Because you mention that this problem started after you imported a library project my guess is that the issue is realted to how you are using the library. Here are some things to try:

You need to make sure you add the library properly. There is a right and a wrong way to add a library to your project. For the correct way right click your project Properties --> Android and add your library here. There is more on how to do this correctly in the [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html). Check to see if that helps.